# Destructuring of optional props in Typescript

Tags: typescript, destructuring

Suppose I have object with optional props of this kind of shape

```
interface MyObject {
  requiredProp: SomeType;
  optionalProp?: { 
    innerData: {
      innerProp1: string;
      innerProp2: number;
      innerProp3?: boolean;
    }
  }
}

const obj:MyObject = { ... }
```

But it seems that I can't easily destructure that `optionalProp`

```
const {innerProp1, innerProp2, innerProp3} = obj.optionalProp?.innerData;
```

because

> Property 'innerProp1' does not exist on type '... | undefined'.

and same for the rest of destructured variables.

Is there an elegant and short way to do this keeping the type safety?

Comment: Just provide a fallback: `obj.optionalProp?.innerData ?? {}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the empty object as a fallback.

```js
const {innerProp1, innerProp2, innerProp3} = obj.optionalProp?.innerData ?? {};
```

But you should remember to check that each innerProp is not undefined before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other correct answers, this can also be addressed in few other ways...

1. By giving a value so that destructuring can be satisfied in case of `undefined` or `null`

```ts
const { innerProp1, innerProp2, innerProp3 } = obj.optionalProp?.innerData || {};
```

2. By doing a `null-ness` check of `optionalProp` before destructuring.

```ts
if (obj.optionalProp) {
    const { innerProp1, innerProp2, innerProp3 } = obj.optionalProp?.innerData;
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with the way 2 that `innerProps{1,2,3}` are defined inside inner block and only if `obj.optionalProp` is not null. So this assumes quite a bit about the surrounding usage. I think you should use question mark operator instead:
`const {innerProp1, innerProp2, innerProp3 } = obj.optionalProp ? obj.optionalProp?.innerData  : {};`

Comment: But then it is just a small leap to more succinct TS/JS using `||` or `?? ` operator.

Comment: @FooF, Already in the other answer `??` was used, so this time I thought to put up `||` which works too, even with lower/older versions of TS/JS... For the second being `block-scoped` indeed, but the point being addressed is `destructuring` involving a `nullable` variable. And so `...this can also be addressed in few other ways...`.